# Access params inside model + rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The code is as follows

```
 def update
    # params = {"from_zip"=>"28803", "lane_week_day_names"=>["Wednesday", "Monday"]}
    @lane.assign_attributes(params)
    
    return unless @lane.valid?

    # rest of logic
  end
```

Model is defined as follows

```
validate :duplicate_lane
has_many :lane_week_days

 def lane_week_day_names
    lane_week_days.map(&:day)
 end

 def lane_week_day_names=(daynames)
    Date::DAYNAMES.each do |dayname|
      existing = lane_week_days.find { |week_day| week_day.day == dayname }
      if daynames.include?(dayname)
        lane_week_days.build(day: dayname) if existing.blank?
      else
        existing&.mark_for_destruction
      end
   end
 end
```

Model validation is defined as follows

```
def duplicate_lane
   #need to get lane_week_day_names form the params
   #compare lane_week_day_names from the params with existing records

    errors.add(:base, "Invalid")
  end
```

I need to get the lane_week_day_names which is available in params to be accessed inside the model. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this, but you have to change the params names to another name because you have a method with the same name.

```
# app/models/lane.rb

attr_accessor :another_params_name

def duplicate_lane
  self.another_params_name # you'll get the value here.
end
```

Thanks :)